# How can I connect my computer to internet through my Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: 7.x, internet-sharing, 3g

I am traveling a lot and I need to be online on my laptop. How can I use 3G connection of my phone to browse internet on my PC?

I have Samsung Omnia 7.

Comment: Tethering on 4GB Verizon Samsung may be "free" but it chews up your allotted 4 g's bigtime! So if you use it, be very careful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Internet sharing or "Tethering" is an option that is not available on all Windows Phone devices. it is a feature that can be build by one of the OEM's

**HTC** provides tethering on their devices and it can be found in the settings menu.

There are rumours on **Nokia** working on an update to provide it on their Windows Phone devices as well.

I'm not to sure about **Samsung** providing this but found this workaround on the internet explaining how to get tethering working on a samsung device (only through usb cable not wifi)

the workaround for **Samsung** devices: (not supported by Microsoft or Samsung and untested by me)

- Connect 'phone to PC with USB.
- Dial ##634# -> Diagnosis app (you will only have to do this once,
  thereafter it will be shown in your apps list).
- Diagnosis code *#7284# -> option to tether via USB modem; take this
  option, it will restart your 'phone.
- Special driver will install on PC, 'phone will then be listed as a
  modem.
- Connect to modem, dial string is *99***1# (no userid/password).
- To return to normal (Zune) USB mode, use diagnosis code *#7284# again
  and select Zune sync (again this will restart your 'phone).

I haven't tested this workaround since i don't own a Samsung device. i just found the instructions [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wptips/samsung-omnia-w-tethering/7b238a91-8b07-4f67-a427-a6729ef49605)

Comment: I wonder if this workaround can affect my device guarantee. If not, I would try that...

Comment: Nokia does expose this functionality, at least on my Nokia Lumia 900. You just need to purchase the 5GB data plan from AT&T to give you access to turn it on.

Comment: Yes @sidran i think it is already available for the lumia 900. On the 800 and 710 we're still waiting on the firmware update

Comment: I think some carriers will charge separately the Tethering.

Comment: There is an important typo in the first sentence of this answer: "that is on available"  Is "on" supposed to be "not"?  Also, I have an HTC Trophy (Verizon) and see no "tethering" or "Internet Sharing" option in settings on my phone.

Comment: @michael maddox thanks for the typo. i changed "on" to "not"

Answer (score 3):

In "Settings" some devices have an option labelled "Internet Sharing" which can turn your phone into a mobile Wi-Fi hotspot. This feature isn't disabled on some devices, and on some networks, but if it is there on your device, that's the option to use.

Comment: I am using HTC Radar and Wi-Fi Hotspot feature is available on my phone

Answer (score 1):

For the **Dell Venue Pro** there are steps and drivers to enable USB tethering is [this thread.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1281744)  Wifi tethering is not possible on the DVP.

Whilst the phone is in USB tethering mode it cannot sync with Zune until the untether process is carried out, all other phone functions are unaffected.

This does not require the phone to be unlocked or rooted, and the process can easily be reversed.

The steps for Windows 7 are:

**Tether:**

1. Download the HTC and Qualcomm Drivers from the bottom of [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1281744)
2. Extract the zip, ignore the XAP.
3. Open the phone dialer. Dial ##634# (Engineering Mode)
4. Slide open your keyboard
5. Tap the black area of your screen under the buttons
6. Type 'qwertyuiop', and extra buttons should appear
7. Scroll down and click on service center button
8. Click on Composite button
9. Type in *#301# as password
10. Wait for your phone to reboot
11. Install the drivers for the phone with the files in the zip.
12. Note that you have to right click the unknown device, update drivers, browser, let me pick, all, I have disc, and then browse to where you extracted your drivers
13. In the device manager (you should be there already) right click on the first HTC USB modem and go to properties
14. Then go to advanced and enter +CGDCONT=1,"IP","EPN.TMOBILE.COM" into the Extra initialization commands box (Note that these settings are for t-mobile. If you do
    not use t-mobile please download and find your connection info [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/show...php?p=21421101). Replace
    epn.tmobile.com with your carriers connection info.
15. Click ok
16. In your system tray, right click on the network icon and go to network and
    sharing center
17. click on 'Set up a new connection or network'
18. Setup 'Set up a dial-up connection'
19. Select HTC USB Modem (Or Qualcomm Usb Modem)
20. In the phone number type *99#
21. Click connect
22. Have fun

**Untether**

If you want to untether, follow steps 3-10 and click on Zune to switch your phone back into normal sync  mode

Note, for me I didn't need to perform steps 13 and 14 for it to work, but you may need to depending on your network.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with Verizon Wireless regarding tethering for the HTC Windows Phone 8x. They tell me that tethering comes free with the 4GB plan. I only have the 2GB plan, so I cannot confirm. It is certainly built into the phone, but disabled by Verizon Wireless.

Answer (score 0):

### LG Optimus Quantum

This phone was meant to have internet sharing available as a feature when Mango was rolled out, but it evidently failed FCC/Industry Canada [SAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_absorption_rate) testing. [(as explained here)](http://www.facebook.com/LGCanada/posts/10150725301499377)

However, if you *really* need the feature (and likely stuck in some sort of contract) it is possible to [flash this particular phone with a firmware from an Australian provider](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1337044) (use at your own risk).