# How do I enable WiFi Hotspot?

Tags: wifi, internet-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I connect my computer to internet through my Windows Phone device?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-can-i-connect-my-computer-to-internet-through-my-windows-phone-device)

Sometimes one want to use the phones internet on a laptop through WiFi hotspot. But it seems impossible on my phone. [Mobiletechworld.com](http://www.mobiletechworld.com/2011/08/25/windows-phone-7-mango-wifi-hot-spot-feature-is-enabled-by-carriers/) says it is dependent on the carrier, which enables (or in my case disables) the WiFi hotspot feature. Is this true, or is there another way to turn on WiFi hotspot on Windwos Phone 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way for you to find out is to go to the settings panel, scroll down past Wi-Fi and see if "Internet Sharing" is an available option.

If you do not see it, then either the manuafacturer didnt include it or the carrier has disabled it.

Depending on your device, there are hacks to enable the Internet Sharing. I strongly recommend caution if you take that route.