# Internet pass-through for my windows phone 8

Tags: lumia, lumia-520

I am a WP8 user. I wish to use my laptop's internet connection with my windows phone. Before switching to windows, i used to have an htc phone which had a connection wizard providing an internet pass-through.Whereas in WP8 i was unable to find that option. The internet on my laptop works on an Ethernet broadband connection.please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I connect my computer to internet through my Windows Phone device?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/80/how-can-i-connect-my-computer-to-internet-through-my-windows-phone-device)

Comment: @jumbo Not a duplicate. That question is about sharing phone's internet connection with computer, this one's about the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

The phone OS is not relevant when you're going to share your laptop connection. You can create hotspot by using a program called **[Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/)**. The program itself is quite self explanatory, I'm sure you won't have any problems with whole configuration. Sorry for not giving a link, will edit the answer today.

Comment: I agree with this answer. The app I've tested for this is [Virtual Router](https://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) (open source).

Comment: There are plenty of programs allowing you to create hotspot. I have an example of this kind I'd app. Feel free to edit my answer by adding your example.

Comment: In Windows 7+ you can create a hosted network but I think your internet should be provided via Ethernet cable in this case.

Comment: The phone's OS might be somewhat relevant. I used to have an HTC Android phone and there was some HTC software that allowed you to connect your phone via USB and use your PC's internet connection. That might be the connection wizard he is referring to.

Comment: Windows Mobile did the same...